# Boot GRUB2 with Degraded RAID5

Tags: grub2, lvm, mdadm

I am building a custom NAS with Debian Jessie. Has three 4TB hard drives in a software RAID5 configuration. Works perfectly when all three drives are present.

I am trying to test what happens when if a drive goes bad & if i can boot the machine in a degraded state. When i unplug any of the drives & try to boot the computer, I see the following from grub.

```
Unable to find LVM volume system/root
  Volume group "system" not found
  Skipping volume group system
```

Finally, grub gives up & drops me in an initramfs shell.

All three drives are partitioned as follows:

```
$ sudo parted /dev/sda print
Model: ATA ST4000VN000-1H41 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 4001GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name  Flags
 1      1049kB  2097kB  1049kB                     bios_grub
 2      2097kB  4001GB  4001GB                     raid
```

Here's my RAID set up...

```
$ sudo mdadm --detail /dev/md0
/dev/md0:
        Version : 1.2
  Creation Time : Tue Jun 30 12:56:49 2015
     Raid Level : raid5
     Array Size : 7813769216 (7451.79 GiB 8001.30 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 3906884608 (3725.90 GiB 4000.65 GB)
   Raid Devices : 3
  Total Devices : 3
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

  Intent Bitmap : Internal

    Update Time : Wed Jul  1 14:37:11 2015
          State : clean 
 Active Devices : 3
Working Devices : 3
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

           Name : kai:0  (local to host kai)
           UUID : 2743ad66:6b1df25a:5c41ca14:19084f56
         Events : 10286

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8        2        0      active sync   /dev/sda2
       1       8       18        1      active sync   /dev/sdb2
       2       8       34        2      active sync   /dev/sdc2
```

Logical Volume setup...

```
$ sudo lvdisplay
--- Logical volume ---
LV Path                /dev/system/root
LV Name                root
VG Name                system
LV UUID                1A55Kr-IR4x-O1Z8-YXFj-BvUJ-PMcs-uRjEsv
LV Write Access        read/write
LV Creation host, time kai, 2015-06-30 12:57:39 -0400
LV Status              available
# open                 1
LV Size                29.80 GiB
Current LE             7629
Segments               1
Allocation             inherit
Read ahead sectors     auto
- currently set to     4096
Block device           253:0

--- Logical volume ---
LV Path                /dev/system/home
LV Name                home
VG Name                system
LV UUID                h6Piot-XXYn-TBdK-s1Ja-YN1z-Fbdn-Nv72IT
LV Write Access        read/write
LV Creation host, time kai, 2015-06-30 12:57:49 -0400
LV Status              available
# open                 1
LV Size                14.90 GiB
Current LE             3814
Segments               1
Allocation             inherit
Read ahead sectors     auto
- currently set to     4096
Block device           253:2

--- Logical volume ---
LV Path                /dev/system/swap
LV Name                swap
VG Name                system
LV UUID                yh7WRj-w4OW-WV4M-q0hN-NlCx-RPiL-usSz6j
LV Write Access        read/write
LV Creation host, time kai, 2015-06-30 12:57:57 -0400
LV Status              available
# open                 2
LV Size                3.72 GiB
Current LE             953
Segments               1
Allocation             inherit
Read ahead sectors     auto
- currently set to     4096
Block device           253:1

--- Logical volume ---
LV Path                /dev/system/storage
LV Name                storage
VG Name                system
LV UUID                U9M7g3-sL2j-Gut6-TaNJ-BNWN-P3KM-DPpa4z
LV Write Access        read/write
LV Creation host, time kai, 2015-06-30 12:58:03 -0400
LV Status              available
# open                 1
LV Size                7.23 TiB
Current LE             1895262
Segments               1
Allocation             inherit
Read ahead sectors     auto
- currently set to     4096
Block device           253:3
```

And `/etc/fstab`

```
/dev/mapper/system-root /               xfs     noatime         0       1
/dev/mapper/system-home /home           xfs     nodev           0       2
/dev/mapper/system-storage /mnt/storage xfs     nodev,noexec    0       2
/dev/mapper/system-swap none            swap    sw              0       0
```

I did install grub on all three drives like so:

```
$ grub-install /dev/sda
$ grub-install /dev/sdb
$ grub-install /dev/sdc
```

Any ideas why i cannot boot off a degraded array? I appreciate your time.